# Why is the Rendered Image Different from Camera View?

Tags: rendering, camera

In Object Mode I see the Camera view as I've set it up.  However, the Rendered image is zoomed out.  How can I make the Renderer render the view that I've set up?
[image: Rendered Donut]

[image: View from Camera]

Comment: maybe you have keyframed your camera?

Comment: I think that your camera is alright but your viewport is actually zoomed in because you should see camera border, try to zoom out with your mouse wheel in the viewport

Comment: How can I check if I've keyframed my camera?

Comment: I don't understand what it means that my "viewport is actually zoomed in".  This view is the result of clicking the [Camera] icon in the upper-right corner of Object mode.

Comment: Also, keypad 0 gives me the same view as the [Camera] icon.  Nevertheless, I think you're telling me that unless I can see the camera frame in the view port, I won't know what the "real" view is...   ...which leads back to my original question; How can I make the render match keypad 0?

Comment: When you press Numpad 0, it takes your view to the same position and angle of your camera, but you are locked in camera perspective meaning that you can zoom in and out of the view you are seeing as if you were zooming in on a big billboard. If you are sufficiently "zoomed out" (scroll mousewheel), you will see a dark border around the image in the center - the "fully lit part if the image is what will show in the render. If you cannot see this border, scroll your mousewheel to zoom out until you see it - https://ibb.co/f0vgmgh